# Finding "^M" using Python re

Tags: python, regex

I have a file that has occurences of the characters "^M". I want to remove all such occurences.

For this I tried using the following bit of code -

```
re.sub('^M', '', line)
```

Even on multiple attempts i am unable to remove it.

Can anyone please tell me whats wrong with what I am doing and suggest something

Comment: you have to escape `^`. So you need to use `\^M` instead. Please go through regex documentation for these details.

Answer (score 5):

`^` is a meta-character in regular expressions, and it should be escaped, i.e.

```
re.sub('\\^M', '', line)  # 2 backslashes because the backslash needs to be escaped
```

or

```
re.sub(r'\^M')            # no escape needed because of a raw string.
```

But then, this is a fixed string, so you should use `str.replace`, i.e.

```
line.replace('^M', '')
```

---

But then, not always does the `^` and `M` mean that there is *`^` and `M`*, as the `^M` can also be used to mean the ASCII carriage return (U+0013, or Control-M); which in a Python string is `\r`:

```
line.replace('\r', '')
```

... but then there is already a utility that will strip these Windows line endings from a file: `dos2unix`.

Comment: Thank you so much Antti.. The line.replace('^M', '') works for most cases.. There are some other cases where there is a string "^MBGP", that does not get replaced. The line.replace('\r', '') also does not work.. Can you help me with that? I am running this on a Mac on a log file

Comment: @SadMad interesting, so there *is* `^` and `M` then. If these do not work, I am unable to help really without further details. Perhaps you should try printing the `repr` of that line: `print(repr(line))` to find out if there are special characters in there.